# Xdebug Netbeans Php Docker

Tags: php, netbeans, docker, xdebug

I start through browser via `http://dev.app/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug`and best I could get is page holds, execution is halted, but Netbeans doesn't stop on breakpoint but keeps waiting for connection. That's when I set proxy in Netbeans on 127.0.0.1:10000.

It makes more logic to put there ip of docker machine 192.168.99.100 but then page is just loaded, nothing stops (docker toolkit on win 8.1). Also when I leave out proxy in Netbeans nothing stops.

When something is listening on 10000 execution is halted where I put breakpoint but Netbeans is waiting for connection. Xdebug is installed and listed in `php -v` and `php -m`.I did expose port 10000.

Debugger port, project url and session id are set in Netbeans.

Xdebug [docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) say when you set `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` you don't need to specify remote host.

I use xdebug.ini from [here](https://github.com/prooph/docker-files/blob/master/php/config/xdebug.ini) used by this [container](https://github.com/prooph/docker-files/blob/master/php/7.0-fpm-xdebug)

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
; port 9000 is used by php-fpm
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
; no need for remote host
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
php-fpm:
    build:
        context: ./php-fpm
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-70
    volumes_from:
        - application
    expose:
        - "9000"
        - "10000"
    ports:
        - "10000:10000"
    links:
        - workspace
    environment:
        PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=dev.app"

nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes_from:
        - application
    volumes:
        - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    links:
        - php-fpm
```

Edit: Here is the xdebug.log when I listen on 192.168.99.1:10000 in Netbeans, execution holded but nb still waiting connection. Win firewall disabled. I did stopping debug from nb.

```
Log opened at 2016-05-26 09:38:04
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 192.168.99.1:10000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/x
debug" fileuri="file:///var/www/laravel/public/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:
language_version="7.0.6" protocol_version="1.0" appid="6" idekey="netbeans-xdebu
g"><engine version="2.4.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Re
thans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Cop
yright (c) 2002-2016 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/db
gp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2016-05-26 09:38:25

root@b42a5193d501:/tmp#
```

Edit2:

Xdebug binds outside the vm, php socket does [connect](http://image.prntscr.com/image/de176b3ee0ad471496ddb83e48e51e80.png), it's about Netbeans not sending proper data. [Path mapping](http://image.prntscr.com/image/29e0eb1be85e49998fc831fe11dcc291.png) in Netbeans.

Idea how to debug? Wireshark?

And this is netstat when debugging is started and Netbeans is waiting for connection

```
C:\Windows\System32>netstat -np TCP | find "10000"
  TCP    192.168.99.1:10000     192.168.99.1:57084     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.99.1:10000     192.168.99.100:55650   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.99.1:57084     192.168.99.1:10000     ESTABLISHED
```

This is netstat inside vm machine

```
docker@default:~$ sudo netstat -plnt | grep ':10000'
tcp        0      0 :::10000                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Also `telnet ::1 10000` connects, and `telnet 192.168.99.1 10000` or `telnet 192.168.99.100 10000` do not, so I think I located the problem, docker vm is expecting connection on :1 ip6 which is strange because i disabled it on whole windows?

Answer (score 2):

I'am also using Netbeans, php-fpm+nginx inside containers via Docker Compose. And just made it work. But my host OS is linux (openSuse Tumbleweed)

## My steps

### 1

On your host system (where your IDE is running) allow **incoming TCP** connections to port specified in Netbeans' settings (yellow).
[image]
 Think about firewall, antivirus and so on.

### 2

Make sure xdebug installed in Docker container where php is running. Example of dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS icu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql intl \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.7.0RC2 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && touch /tmp/xdebub.log
```

Make sure that specified versions of xdebug and php [are compatible](https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=xdebug&release=2.7.0RC2).
You can execute `php -i | grep xde` inside php container to check that all goes fine and xdebug is enabled.

### 3

Somehow provide xdebug config inside container with php. You may add `echo`s to dockerfile, or COPY it from host to container while building.
I've ended up with this:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

In my case xdebug.idekey (red higlighting on the pic) is passed by browser extension through XDEBUG_SESSION cookie. And it didn't work until I removed `remote_autostart` and `default_enable` from xdebug's config.

#### Note for win and mac users

Seems `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` won't works on your systems. You may need set it to 0 and add `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal`. Links: [about macos](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds), [about windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds).

### 4

Configure project path mapping.
[image]

### Thats all

While configuring I've faced several times that IDE  blocks the port or somethig like that. 
At host's terminal it looks like

```
> sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 9000
java      28134 username  214u  IPv6 929551      0t0  TCP 172.20.10.1:9000->172.20.10.3:54104 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

In this case IDE restart helps.

---

In OP's example there's no need to expose any ports from php-fpm container nor 9000 nor 10000. Within xdebug session php-fpm process connects to IDE so IDE is listening on port, not php-fpm. Also this isn't a problem that php-fpm uses port 9000, it listening this port on another interface, and it won't conflicts with IDE.